# Hadoop 2.6.0 how to configure job to have less running mappers

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have some jobs that are long-time running but not that important.. some cleaning/indexing jobs... If I am running the job right now I am blocking rest of jobs. all new jobs stay in queue in pending mode..
What I would like is: reduce number of running mappers for a specific job. Can I do that?

Comment: I don't think, you can control no. of mappers, as no. of mappers = no. of blocks in which the file is divided across the nodes.

Also, Hadoop framework gives flexibility to provide the no. of reducers but not mappers during configuration.

But, I am also curious now about how to handle your case.

Comment: well I don't need to control the # of mappers because I know how to do that. I can write my own splitter.. but I would like to limit the # of running mappers...